# discrepancy in span width between React and pure HTML implementation

Tags: css, reactjs

I was trying to figure out how to apply horizontal space between elements using ReactJS when I noticed a discrepancy that I can't explain.

SSCCE below: (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laq2r7ay/))

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <span>foo</span>
    <span style='display:inline-block; width:30px'></span>
    <span>bar</span>
    <div id='div0'></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js">    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var rce = React.createElement.bind(React);
     var x = (rce('div', {}
       , rce('span', {}, 'foo')
       , rce('span', {style: {display: 'inline-block', width: '30px'}})
       , rce('span', {}, 'bar')));
     ReactDOM.render(x, document.getElementById('div0'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code produces on the output:

[image]

Given that the DOM elements are identical (except for the presence of the `data-reactid` attributes):

[image]

Why then, this discrepancy in the spacing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of spacing in your HTML code between inline html elements. React removes it by default.

```
    <span>foo</span><span style='display:inline-block; width:30px'></span><span>bar</span>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9kxxqovr/)

Same result can be achieved with commenting space in your HTML code.

```
<span>foo</span><!-- 
--><span style='display:inline-block; width:30px'></span><!-- 
--><span>bar</span>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/79mL41k2/)

Also the code actually does differ. As you can notice there is no whitespace in React's generated HTML.

[image]

Comment: I 've accepted your answer but I think I ought to delete the question. It's not likely to help anybody else since it's not React related at all.

Comment: don't delete this. This saved my day!